# Default font on Jelly Bean 4.2.2?

Tags: android, fonts, typeface

What is the default font type on **Jelly Bean 4.2.2** ? Also what does the typeface **'normal'** refer to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html  . Normal means regular with medium size

Comment: Which font among the Roboto family is set as default ?